# Custom Map Widget With Zone Marker In Cumulocity

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to implement a custom map widget/plugin which will showcase specific zones with color.
Now using out of the box map widget it is not possible to achieve the same in cumulocity. Is there any way I can do the same using custom development?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can easily create a custom widget using the guide for [angularjs](https://cumulocity.com/guides/web/web-sdk-for-plugins/) or [angular](https://cumulocity.com/guides/web/angular/). Try to use the Angular SDK!

"showcase specific zones with color" -> I recommend you use a library for the map. In angularjs we use ngmap with nice results (as you can see), but there are many of them. For the zones you can create managedobjects in the inventory with a specific type like "customZone" and then use them to show the zone on the map.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I was able to load a map with markers and zones with leaflet js using HTML widget. I will try out the angular option also.